# how to import and export asynchronous function on javascript?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, javascript-import

i have this asynchronous function

```
//example get
  async getDatafromAPINODE(url) {
    try {
      let respond = await axios.get(API_URL_NODE + url, {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Authorization: "Bearer " + this.state.tokenUser,
        },
      });
      if (respond.status >= 200 && respond.status < 300) {
        console.log("respond Post Data", respond);
      }
      return respond;
    } catch (err) {
      let respond = err;
      console.log("respond Post Data err", err);
      return respond;
    }
  }
```

how can i make this function export-able ? so i can use in another file with `import`

Comment: ...yes? Did you have some problems when you tried it?

Comment: Yes it is possible, multiple ways. If you want to use import statements and this is a web implementation then look into [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/). Or a simpler solution would be to just put this into a separate .js file and add that script first, then just call it, or TBH about 100 different solutions. You need to do some research

Comment: Just write `export async function getDatafromAPINODE(url) {…}`

Comment: just edit my answer. could you please upvote the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok this what im doing

```
//asyncFunction.js
export const getDatafromAPINODE = async (url, props) => {
  try {
    let respond = await axios.get(API_URL_NODE + url, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: "Bearer " + props,
      },
    });
    if (respond.status >= 200 && respond.status < 300) {
      console.log("respond Post Data", respond);
    }
    return respond;
  } catch (err) {
    let respond = err;
    console.log("respond Post Data err", err);
    return respond;
  }
};
```

then i called using

```
import {getDatafromAPINODE} from '../../../helper/asyncFunction'
```

as you can see im using 2 args url and props, the props will be used for getting the token for my need